# Whether Speex codec is suitable for Mobile VOIP Applications?

Tags: codec, mobile-application, speex

I have been implementing `VOIP` in our mobile application. In voice `encoding/decoding`, I heard that the `SPEEX codec` is good for improving quality. Eventhough it has good quality, I have afraid to use it because in speex document they mentioned as "`Speex is not designed for mobile phones but rather for packet networks and voice over IP (VoIP) applications`".
Could any one knows why SPEEX codec is not suitable for mobile applications however it has lot of features rather than G711, G722 ...etc?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed Speex is not designed for mobile phones but it meet all the requirements for mobile devices

- Low CPU usage
- Effective audio compression
- Good voice quality

also there is many success mobile apps using it such [Zello](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.loudtalks) and many others